# Amount of selected listview items?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm trying to do a for loop to do something. As long as i, is less than the amount of selected items in listview1. Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.(amountofselecteditems?); i++)
```

Is there a way to do this?
Edit:
This is what i have now.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                selectedClient = listView1.SelectedItems[i].Text;
                Chatserver.DisconnectClient(selectedClient);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

            }     

        }
```

Here's my DisconnectClient method:

```
public void DisconnectClient(string ClientName)
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in this.CONNECTIONS_TABLE)
                {
                    if ((string)dictionaryEntry.Value == ClientName)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ((Socket)dictionaryEntry.Key).Close();
                            break;
                        }
                        catch (Exception )
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: listView1.SelectedItems.Count

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The collection of selected items is called `SelectedItems`. If you want to get its length, then it would be `SelectedItems.Count`. So the full expression would be `listView1.SelectedItems.Count`.

In the `for` loop, when you want to access each selected item, you would do it like so:

```
listView1.SelectedItems[i]
```

I don't see the issue in your `DisconnectClient` method. One thing to check is that the text of the selected items actually matches client names. You really should debug this.

Also, you should use generics for the dictionary.

Comment: I just used what you wrote, and it does not keep deleting the selected items. What could be wrong?

Comment: @Qube In your code you aren't deleting the selected items... why _would_ they get deleted?

Comment: No i'm sorry i wanted to disconnect them, look at the code.

Comment: @Qube I would need to know the specifics of your `ChatServer.DisconnectClient` method to know the answer then.

Comment: It just disconnect by name, which is in the listview. Lets say i have 3 clients selected in the listview. It should disconnect selected 1, selected 2, selected 3.

Comment: The code in your question should do exactly that. The problem is in your `DisconnectClient` method.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a foreach loop instead of a for loop unless you need to track the index:

```
foreach (var item in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    // item is a selected item
}
```